# how do i get the footer to stay at the very bottom? css

Tags: html, css

The footer will be at the bottom permanently visible and not just when you get to the very bottom of the page as I want.

```
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <ul class="footer-info">
      <li>ex</li>
      <li>Contact on:</li>
      <li>ex@gmail.com</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #3E8DA8;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-info li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: If you dont want fixed position on the bottom of the screen, dont use position: fixed; 
You can check easy explanation od positioning on this page:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Give the footer class to the actual footer tag, not the div inside,

```
 <footer class="footer">
      <ul class="footer-info">
        <li>ex</li>
        <li>Contact on:</li>
        <li>ex@gmail.com</li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `bottom: 0;`:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer{
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #3E8DA8;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
} 

.footer-info li {
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <ul class="footer-info">
      <li>ex</li>
      <li>Contact on:</li>
      <li>ex@gmail.com</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

my advice to you is to learn all the basics ASAP